# Test Crashed Caught unexpected signal: SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access

Tags: c, capitalization, capitalize

I solved the codewars training as below. I'm getting an error message, what's wrong in the code? I don't know what is going on, so please let me know.
**But it is capitalizing every word!**

I passed: 111 tests
Failed: 1
Errors: 1
Exit Code: 1

**Test Crashed Caught unexpected signal: SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access. **

It is a Jaden Casing Strings (**It is capitalizing every word!**)

```
char *to_jaden_case (char *jaden_case, const char *string){
// write to jaden_case and return it
  int i = 0;
  if(*(string) <= 'z' && *(string) >= 'a'){
    *(jaden_case) = *(string) - 32;
  }
  else{
    *(jaden_case) = *(string);
  }
  for(i = 1;*(string + i) != '\0'; i++){
    if( *(string + i - 1) == ' '){
      if(*(string + i) <= 'z' && *(string + i) >= 'a'){
        *(jaden_case + i) = *(string + i) - 32;
      }
      else{
        *(jaden_case + i) = *(string + i);
      }
    }
    else{
      *(jaden_case + i) = *(string + i);
    }
  }
  *(jaden_case + i) = '\0';
  return jaden_case;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is someone holding family pets hostage on pain of death if you use the `[` and `]` characters in your source, or are those keys just broken?

Comment: The kata is [Jaden Casing Strings](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5390bac347d09b7da40006f6), for reference.

Comment: Anyway, your code will not bode well with the special case of an empty string, `""`, as the source, and a `char[1]` as the target. Plot that case on paper and you should discover a pretty important problem.

Comment: `jaden_case[ i ] = toupper( ( unsigned char ) string[ i ] );`

Comment: Debugger.......

Comment: Simpler code, fewer complex exprrssions  more intermediale, temporary vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first test case is the empty string:

```
Test(tests_suite, fixed_tests)
{
  sample_test(
    "",
    ""
  );
  /* ... */
```

In that case, the following

```
for(i = 1;*(string + i) != '\0'; i++)
```

will cause [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when accessing an invalid index via `string[1]`.

---

Consider using the functions found in [`<ctype.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), such as [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) and especially [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) to solve this.

Generally, consider using the syntax `foo[n]`, instead of `*(foo + n)`.

That said, the minimal change required for your code is to place the `for` loop inside a guarding `if` that checks if the string is at least one character long.

```
if (*string) {
   for (/* ... */) {
       /* ... */
}
```

I might suggest doing this, and then having a look at the more well received [solutions](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5390bac347d09b7da40006f6/solutions/c).